# Regex returning unwanted comma and period afterwards

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that includes the following in google apps script:

```
data.match(/\[[0-9]+(\.)?[0-9]?[0-9]? G\]/).toString().match(/[0-9]+(\.)?[0-9]?[0-9]?/).toString();
```

The regular expressions that I have work in pulling out the numbers that I need from the string (called 'data' above) but for some reason this code adds a comma after all numbers without a decimal and a a decimal and then a comma in numbers with a decimal, and I need to get it to stop doing that. I just want the number.

In order to anticipate the first question I'm sure I'll get, the two different match sequences are to narrow the string down since there are a lot of similarly formatted numbers in the string I'm searching. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do that but that's not what I'm looking for.

This really has me stumped, even though I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the .match() function returns an array of matches, calling .toString() on it will give a comma separated string containing the elements of the array.

if you don't want the elements to be separated you can use join("")

Comment: Thanks, any insight into why I was getting a period followed by a comma in numbers with a decimal (9.0 would give 9.0.,). Maybe something do do with the way my regular expression worked? That has me confused still.

Comment: calling .toString() on an array returns one string containing each array element separated by commas. for example ["hi", "there", "!"].toString() will return "hi,there,!"

for more check this article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)